# Akka BalancingPool: No group variant?

Tags: scala, akka, load-balancing

I am trying to implement load balancing for a set of Akka actors. According to the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html), `BalancingPool` offers the behavior that I am interested in (work stealing). For some reason, there is no "group variant" which would allow me to create the routees myself and pass them to the router. The docs explicitly say

> There is no Group variant of the BalancingPool.

without saying why. My actor's constructor is called with arguments that are calculated at runtime, so I have no other option but creating them programmatically.

```
val resources:List[Any] = // ...
val system = ActorSystem("MySystem")
val routees = resources.map(r => system.actorOf(MyActor.props(r))
// This doesn't work for me, because every actor needs a resource!
val router = system.actorOf(BalancingPool(3).props(Props[MyActor]), "router")
```

How do I create a `BalancingPool` router that forwards all messages to my actors? Why is there no `BalancingGroup`?

Comment: I assume there is not BalancingGroup, since the routees have to share a single mailbox. However when you create the routees yourself each one already has its own mailbox.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to make `BalancingPool` work with your actors as written, but you can change your actors so that they receive an initial message that gives them the information they need to setup. If you add this class:

```
case class Setup(getResource: () => Any)
```

And these lines to your actor:

```
def receive = {
  case Setup(getResource) => {
    context.become(afterSetupReceive(getResource()))
  }
}

def afterSetupReceive(resource: Any) = {
  /* put cases from original recieve  here */
}
```

You can create your customized BalancedPool like:

```
val router = system.actorOf(BalancingPool(resources.length).props(Props[MyActor]), "router")
val resourcesIter = resources.iterator
val getResource = () => resourcesIter.synchronized {
  resourcesIter.next
}
router ! Broadcast(Setup(getResource))
```

The synchronized wrapper around the iterator is hideous, but this will let you work around the limitations in `BalancedPool`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Would have never thought of that myself :) I am getting a weird error though: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f8f09897e667db4d176b. Seems like BalancingPool is creating actors with invalid names?

Comment: @wingedsubmariner I am not sure this works reliably (due to the shared mailbox) (see also this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/akka-user/D-qVGymeIKw/irpb1uIqtdEJ)) and support for sending Broadcast messages to a BalancedPool is supposed to be removed: https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/15030

Comment: @VolkerStampa Now that I think about it, it makes sense. Do you have a suggestion how to address that issue in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Since broadcasting to a BalancePool is not a good idea, I came up with a workaround. Instead of sending the broadcast, I created a synchronized queue in the actor's companion object, containing the resources. Upon creation, each actor dequeues an element from that queue. Not a pretty solution, but it works.

```
// Router creation
val router = system.actorOf(BalancingPool(resources.length).props(Props[MyActor]), "router")

// In MyActor.scala
class MyActor {
  val resource = MyActor.resourceQueue.dequeue()

  // ...
}

object MyActor {
  val resourceQueue = {
    val queue = new mutable.SynchronizedQueue[MyResource]()
    queue.enqueue(...) // <-- resources
    queue
  }
}
```